# Handling (type | undefined) checks in interfaces with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here, I'm trying to check if there's a "booster" (Card[]) that is in the boostersToGo variable in a player interface. If there is, I want to shift() it and make that the currentBooster.

However, Typescript is giving me an error:

```
message: 'Type 'Card[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Card[]'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Card[]'.'
```

My editor (VSCode) is underlining player.currentBooster in red here. What's going on? I have had similar issues before using typescript but have hacked around them a little bit. What's the proper way to deal with this?

```
if (player.boostersToGo.length > 0) {
    player.currentBooster = player.boostersToGo.shift()
}
//player is guaranteed to fit the interface Player because that's what's explicitly passed into the function

export interface Player {
    boostersToGo: Card[][]
    currentBooster: Card[]
    picks: Card[][]
    human: boolean
}

export interface Card {
    name: string
    manaCost: string
    colors?: string[]
    cmc: number
    types: string[]
    rarity: string
    imageUrl: string
    pick?: boolean
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try this <Card[]>player.boostersToGo.shift()

Comment: Fixed. I guess I have to cast everything that could be undefined? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce it in http://www.typescriptlang.org, so maybe it's related with your `TypeScript` / `IntelliSense` version, which will also change your [`lib.d.ts`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html#libdts) definitions.

It may be worth trying to quickly run a bigger portion of your problematic code in there and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't, maybe upgrading to the latest `TypeScript` version or updating `VSCode` will help.

Otherwise, you can always enforce a type with [Type Assertion (casting)](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html):

```
if (player.boostersToGo.length > 0) {
    player.currentBooster = player.boostersToGo.shift() as Card[];
}
```

Comment: For the error to be effected the `strictNullChecks` (or the encompassing `strict`) compiler option needs to be set to `true`.

Comment: Another option is to use TypeScript's [non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator): `player.currentBooster = player.boostersToGo.shift()!;`